# Running SQLite3 on AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, sqlite, amazon-web-services, npm, aws-lambda

I am trying to connect to a sqlite3 database on my node.js AWS Lambda function. The Code runs perfectly when i test it localy but when i upload it to AWS Lambda i get the following Error Message:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/var/task/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v48-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3.js:4:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

It seems that the AWS Lambda function trys to access the node-v48-linux-x64 folder which is not present in my npm installation because i am using Windows for the development.

Anyone knows how to fix this issue or how to get the content of the node-v48-linux-x64 folder?

Comment: Are you running Linux locally?

Comment: No, i only have Windows locally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you did an `npm install` on your Windows computer and then uploaded this `node_modules` directory together with your Lambda function.

Running `npm install` on your Windows computer basically built the `sqlite` packages with bindings for Windows instead of Linux which AWS Lambda uses. Bindings for Windows do not work on Linux.

The solution is to do your `npm install` on a Linux machine and then upload this `node_modules` directory (which is created on Linux) together with your Lambda function.

To do that you can either,

- Use a Linux VM (e.g. Virtualbox, `vagrant`, etc.) in your Windows machine and do your `npm install` there.
- Use `docker` locally.
- Use an `sqlite` package that is written in pure javascript (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sqlite-purejs)

Comment: Thanks! Running npm install sqlite3 on a Linux 64Bit did the Job!

Comment: I suggest docker, to replicate exactly the same server environment, including the same node version that might trigger errors on lambda. Virtualbox would work too, but it's a bit overhead and download time when you work on multiple applications. More details here https://medium.com/@elvisciotti/how-to-create-a-serverless-microservice-node-js-sqlite-44888abb3847

Answer (score 2):

You can solve doing this installing a cross-platform version of sqlite3. 
First install sqlite3 in your project:

```
npm install sqlite3
```

Then install node-pre-gyp globally:

```
npm install -g node-pre-gyp
```

And use node-pre-gyp to install sqlite3 for linux

```
node-pre-gyp install --directory=./node_modules/sqlite3 --target_platform=linux --target_arch=x64
```

Answer (score 0):

In order local build to work on AWS lambda, architecture, platform and libc should match on both machines, especially if you are using packages(or dependecies) like sqlite, which uses pre-build binaries.

In order to specify arch, platform and libc for target machine during install use this commands.

for npm

```
npm install --target_arch=arm64 --target_platform=linux --target_libc=glibc
```

for yarn

```
npm_config_target_arch=arm64 npm_config_target_platform=linux npm_config_target_libc=glibc yarn install
```

Or just export them before using

```
export npm_config_target_arch=arm64
export npm_config_target_platform=linux
export npm_config_target_libc=glibc

yarn install (or npm install)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can easily generate a lambda layer and attach to your lambda function. Try https://nodelayer.xyz to generate a lambda layer to attach to your function. The layers are run on Amazon Linux 2 docker images which is what the lambda runtime uses.